# Kivy Python - Button to increment variable, without using NumericProperty

Tags: python, kivy

I'm a complete novice to both python and kivy having learnt python from codeacademy about a week ago and kivy from youtube tutorials.

Could someone please explain to me why the code below does not result in a screen with a label displaying n, which is incremented by the button?

Python file

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button, Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty


class Example(BoxLayout):
    n = 0

    def n_plus(self):
        self.n += 1


class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Example()

example = ExampleApp()
example.run()
```

KV file

```
<Example>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            text: str(root.n)
        Button:
            text: "+1"
            on_press: root.n_plus()
```

Then could you explain why making n = NumericProperty(0) makes this work?

I'd like to run some functions on n which don't seem to work on numeric properties.

Comment: One way to look at this, the .kv, it doesn't see what is happening in your python. So you need to "help" .kv "see" the changes happening in python: this is call "binding". Using NumericProperty(0) (or any property like ObjectProperty or StringProperty) is a way of binding. 

This is my understanding so far, I am also starting kivy (a couple of weeks ago) so I am sorry can't be more precise.

Comment: Another way to force .kv to "see" what is happening in python is to update the text of your label in python: http://codepad.org/kg5Kd5pT

Answer (score 1):

Because when you use `NumericProperty()`
As the official document said:

> It produces events such that when an attribute of your object changes,
>   all properties that reference that attribute are automatically
>   updated.

So, in short, it creates a binding relationship between your UI(`.kv`) and attribute of its class(`.py`)

But, actually, you can modify the UI by yourself without the help from the kivy framework. I changed your example as the following:

1. Add an `id` attribute to your widget
2. Access the `id` attribute by using `self.ids.your_id_in_kv_file`

But it's obviously not good, since now you need to update your UIby yourself everytime you want to update your UI. But with that `XXXXProperty` from kivy, you just need to change the value of that attribute, you don't need to worry about the UI at all.

Another disadvantage of the solution is that, when you need to change the UI, you need to change tons of code if you modify them all by yourself...

Here is the example:

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.lang.builder import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

Builder.load_string("""
<Example>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            id: lbl
            text: "0"
        Button:
            text: "+1"
            on_press: root.n_plus()
""")

class Example(BoxLayout):

      def n_plus(self):
         value = self.ids.lbl.text
         self.ids.lbl.text = str(int(value) + 1)


class ExampleApp(App):

    def build(self):
        return Example()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    ExampleApp().run()
```